# Pounds to Kilo Convertor VB.Net Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8.1

Im fairly new to vb.net and windows phone programming, i am trying to make a pounds to kg convertor, here is what i have so far.

```
Private Sub ConvertButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ConvertButton.Click
    Dim Kilo, Pounds As Single
    Kilo = KiloTextBox.Text
    Pounds = PoundTextBox.Text
    KiloTextBox.Text = PoundTextBox.Text * 2.2045855
```

could someone please tell me where i have gone wrong please?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't it do? Try formatting your code and learning how to ask a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: G'day Craig, I have tried the code i have written in the post, sorry if i have asked a "bad question" but we all have to start somewhere.

Comment: Again - what have you tried? What doesn't it do?

Comment: KiloTextBox.Text = PoundTextBox.Text * 2.2045855

Im trying to convert kilos to pounds

Comment: Just to take a stab, it's likely that the textbox Text returns a string and not a number so you won't be able to multiply it.

Comment: And it seems you're trying to convert pounds to kilos, not the other way around.

Comment: ok, what do you recommend? i just checked out your profile and you seem like the guy with the knowledge :)

Comment: You assign the textbox entries to variables then don't use them. Firstly `Dim Kilo, Pounts as single` should be `dim Kilo as single, pounds as single` and I would suggest `KiloTextBox.Text = PoundTextBox.Text * 2.2045855` should be `KiloTextBox.Text = Pounds * 2.2045855`. I would also consider some checking that the entry is a value

Comment: Firstly, does your program compile?

Comment: let me give that a shot, i pretty new at this and unfortunately there is only some much youtube can help with :(

Comment: Yes, it does, however when i say text 50 in to the kilo textbox and press the convert button it will then crash

Comment: OK, when it crashes, what exception do you get?

Comment: Yes, here it is

An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in MICROSOFT.VISUALBASIC.NI.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Single' is not valid.

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt like it, it crashed at the pounds = poundtextbox.text

        Dim Kilo As Single
        Dim Pounds As Single
        Pounds = PoundTextBox.Text
        Kilo = KiloTextBox.Text
        KiloTextBox.Text = Pounds * 2.2045855

Comment: OK, as I said earlier "Just to take a stab, it's likely that the textbox Text returns a string and not a number so you won't be able to multiply it." So you are trying to multiple strings.

Comment: I'd suggest googling "vb.net convert string to double"

Comment: i'll take a look, Thank you for your help!
Just quickly does everything that i have here look ok?

Comment: There's lots of things wrong - e.g. use lower case to start variable names. Kilo is never used. You should probably convert the Pounds sting to the single when you read it from the text.

Comment: If I were you and I wanted to learn to program correctly I'd find a good tutorial that steps you through it. Coming here to ask questions probably isn't going to be very productive.

Comment: Thanks Craig :) Yeah you are right, but good help is hard to find, i made a BMI calculator for windows phone without any problems, i thought that converting kgs to pounds would have been on the same track, but it appears not, anyways man, ill keep the trial and error going hahah, thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the value from string to single - however the string datatype does not widen to a single, that is what the invalid cast exception you receive is telling you. A good place to start would be with learning about the [data types built into .Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx) and what each widens/narrows to.

Once you get a basic understanding of the data types, you next need to figure out how to change a type into the type you need.  In this example you need to change a string to a single.  .Net provides some built-in [type conversion functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) that will help you accomplish this.

I think you would find this on your own eventually, but you asked a question and showed you had put some effort forth, so here is an example how to use the type conversion functions to solve your problem.

---

Now, you will receive another error if you try to convert a string to a single that is not numeric, so we can handle this a couple ways:

Option 1: We check if the string is numeric *before* we attempt to convert.

```
Private Sub ConvertButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ConvertButton.Click
    If IsNumeric(PoundTextBox.Text) Then
        Dim Pounds as Single =  cSng(PoundTextBox.Text)
        KiloTextBox.Text = cStr(Pounds * 2.2045855)
    Else
        KiloTextBox.Text= "Enter a number!"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Option 2:  We use structured error handling:

```
Private Sub ConvertButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ConvertButton.Click
    Try
        Dim Pounds as Single =  cSng(PoundTextBox.Text)
        KiloTextBox.Text = cStr(Pounds * 2.2045855)
    Catch ex As System.InvalidCastException  'We can handle this exception one way
        KiloTextBox.Text= "Enter a number!"
    Catch ex As Exception  'And we can handle other exceptions another way
        Msgbox(Ex.Tostring)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have a visual studio on this computer, but what is the error or exception you are receiving running this?

Comment: Thank you again for your comment, unfortunately this hasn't solved the problem. not too worry but, just thought id try something abit different, Thank you again :) i all start studying up on the different data types :)

Comment: @AndrewEberle - can you provide the exact error message you receive when you try to run this code?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in MICROSOFT.VISUALBASIC.NI.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: i have tried it using this method

  Dim Kilo As Double
        Dim Pounds As Double
        Dim Results As Double
        Kilo = KiloTextBox.Text
        Pounds = PoundTextBox.Text
        Results = (Kilo) / (Pounds * 2.2045855)
        ResultTextBlock.Text = Results

Comment: @AndrewEberle That error indicates that the string you are trying to convert (presumably the contents of a TextBox) is empty. Did you enter something in PoundTextBox? You should always check that the value in the TextBox can be converted to a number (use TryParse).

Comment: @andrew - that exception clearly did not come from the code I wrote as there is no casting as a double which happens in my code. Try the code I wrote. It should do what you need.

Comment: @CBRF23 hey mate, i tried it, but when i pressed the convert button it crashed.

Comment: Interesting! Are you stepping through the code line by line, or running it all at once? At which line does it crash one?

Comment: this is the first way i tried it but i had no luck so thats why my code down here is different from the original post.

Private Sub ConvertButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ConvertButton.Click
    Dim Kilo, Pounds As Single
    Kilo = KiloTextBox.Text
    Pounds = PoundTextBox.Text
    KiloTextBox.Text = PoundTextBox.Text * 2.2045855

Answer (score 1):

try:

KiloTextBox.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(PoundTextBox.Text) * 2.2045855).ToString

Comment: Upvote for simplicity and using newer .NET functions. However you haven't provided a way to handle errors for an input like "ABC" in the pounds textbox.  If you wrapped this in a try/catch I think it would be better.

Comment: no luck unfortunately, Thanks for your help anyways :)